# Filter list in R

Tags: r

I have a problem, I have this output in R:

```
[[155]]
[1] "@ju_kleeschulte" "@c"             

[[156]]
[1] "@FDPFraktionNRW" "@c_lindner"     

[[157]]
[1] "@HenningWerle" "@c_lindner"    "@RTLWEST"     

[[158]]
[1] "@Stefanswelt" "@fdp"
```

But I want to filter out the complete Values (156 & 157) with "@c_lindner" in it, because it is a retweet and I would like the tweets solely without that nametag in it. So, I would like the list to be with the values 155 & 158 for example.
It should look like this:

```
  [[155]]
[1] "@ju_kleeschulte" "@c"             

 [[156]]
[1] "@Stefanswelt" "@fdp"
```

Comment: `lapply(lst[c(156, 157)], function(x) x[x=="@c_lindner"])`

Comment: @akrun yes, but I need to do it to 10 other lists and they are like you see, with 200 Rows minimum. Is there no function, which searches the Values for the tag and automatically filters it?

Comment: Keep it in a list and then do the filtering

Comment: @akrun Can you explain me, what I should keep in the list?

Comment: @akrun yes, it should filter out the whole values and just show me a list, with the values I need (So, without the name tag)

Comment: let's say you have `lst1`, `lst2`, ... `lst10`, `lstN <- mget(paste0("lst", 1:10))`

Comment: Then do `lapply(lstN, function(y) Filter(function(x)  any( x!= "@c_lindner), y))`

Comment: Can you explain the lstN? Is it a new list? Because I can't find anything, when I write it with my code `Error: Value for '‘cln1’' not found` When I type `lstN <- mget(paste0("cln", 1:10))`

Comment: You said 10 lists.  So, I am creating a single list that have all the objects

Comment: Ok, I have to make a list out of them all, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place all the `list` objects in a `list` and then do the `Filter`

```
lapply(lstN, function(y) Filter(function(x) !any(x == "@c_lindner"), y))
```

#### data

```
lstN <- mget(paste0("lst", 1:10))
```

Comment: Thanks so much ;) Works like a charm